# Access fron outside browser to shellinabox site

Tags: centos, port-forwarding

## Server : 192.168.40.23

```
  `# vi /etc/sysconfig/shellinaboxd`
```

---

```
    # TCP port that shellinboxd's webserver listens on 
    PORT=6175
    # specify the IP address of a destination SSH server 
    OPTS="-s /:SSH:192.168.40.23"
    
    # if you want to restrict access to shellinaboxd from localhost only     
#OPTS="-s /:SSH:192.168.40.23 --localhost-only"
 OPTS="--disable-ssl-menu -s /:LOGIN"
```

When i access :
`https://localhost:6175` is works fine on the same server.

When i access from outside with server LAN ip : `https://192.168.40.23:6175` , Browser displays :

> Unable to connect

How to open `6175` for outside browsing ?
Is it issue of firewall or just a miss-configuration of [shellinabox](http://www.tecmint.com/shell-in-a-box-a-web-based-ssh-terminal-to-access-remote-linux-servers/) .

Comment: Do you try access 192.168.40.23 from outside the lan (from internet)? if so you can't access this ip because is a private ip. You have to check with your public ip and eventualy configure your FW to allow traffic on port 6175

Answer (score 0):

```
firewall-cmd --permanent --add-port=6175/tcp
firewall-cmd --reload
```